# Change the language for date in php

Tags: php, date

I have this MySQL query, which returns two dates (which are both formatted as a-m-Y). Now I want to translate this date into my own language (Danish). How can I do that.
I have tried both the setlocale() and strftime() functions, but it won't work.
I know it's a very basic question, but i really need help :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 14):

I found that `setlocale` isn't reliable, as it is set per process, not per thread (the manual mentions this). This means other running scripts can change the locale at any time. A solution is using [IntlDateFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php) from the `intl` php extension.

- Install `intl` if necesarry (ubuntu): `sudo apt-get install php5-intl`
- Install the locale you want to use (I'm using italian as an example): `sudo locale-gen it_IT`
- Generate a locally formatted date:

```php
$fmt = new \IntlDateFormatter('it_IT', NULL, NULL);
$fmt->setPattern('d MMMM yyyy HH:mm'); 
// See: https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#datetime-format-syntax for pattern syntax
echo $fmt->format(new \DateTime()); 
// Output: 6 gennaio 2016 12:10
```

Comment: This is the best answer, as it doesn't change the global locale.

Answer (score 12):

Use `setlocale` and `strftime` together:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, array('da_DA.UTF-8','da_DA@euro','da_DA','danish'));
echo strftime("%A"); // outputs 'tirsdag'
```

Works on my php installation on Windows.

> strftime(): Warning! This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 8.1.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

Comment: But can I output variables with that method?

Comment: What do you mean? What variables do you want to output?

Comment: I store the date-data from the query in variables. I don't wanna output the current date ...

Comment: For storing dates/times I would use the appropiate datatype in your database design (like a timestamp or datetime). You can however of course just store the return value of `strftime` in a variable: `$date = strftime("%A");`

Comment: Yes you can Emil Just pass your variable as a second parametre: strftime("%A", $yourdate);

Answer (score 7):

Use

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'da_DA');

echo strftime("%A %e %B %Y");
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the `date()` function is quite evolved enough for you, here.

Instead, I would recommend you take a look at the [**`IntlDateFormatter`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php)<sup>1</sup> class *(quoting)* :

> Date Formatter is a concrete class that enables **locale-dependent
>   formatting**/parsing of dates using pattern strings and/or canned
>   patterns.

There are a couple of examples on the manual page of [`IntlDateFormatter::format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.format.php), where that method is used to display a date in two different languages, by just setting the desired locale.

<sup>1.</sup> <sub>bundled with PHP >= 5.3</sub>

Comment: That looks kind of complex :D Okay, I'll take a look at it.
I can't understand that it can be that hard to just change the language :)

Comment: Well, you must have "something" that can generate the string in the right language -- which means knowing the words, their order, ... and that's not an easy task.

Answer (score 1):

**This Will Surely works for you if you want norwegian date and month format**

```
$date = '2016-11-16 05:35:14';
setlocale(LC_TIME, array('nb_NO.UTF-8','nb_NO@norw','nb_NO','norwegian'));
echo strftime("%e %b %Y",strtotime($date));
```

**if you want to get other language locale ids like nb_NO then refer this site**
[International Components for Unicode (ICU) Data](https://www.localeplanet.com/icu/)

Answer (score -5):

If you are trying to convert a `datetime` try this:

```
$fecha = $dateConsulta->format('d-M-Y');  
$fecha = str_replace('Jan','Ene',$fecha);
$fecha = str_replace('Apr','Abr',$fecha);
$fecha = str_replace('Aug','Ago',$fecha);
$fecha = str_replace('Dec','Dic',$fecha);
```