# Get date('F') in a different language CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to change the language of the outputted date from `date()` in CodeIgniter.

I have put all the required files in `application/language/swedish/*` and tried setting the variable `$config['language'] = 'swedish';`. However `date('F', strtotime('2017-07-01'));` still outputs `July` and not `Juli`.

Comment: Use `strftime`.

Comment: Check this [Change the language for date in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910912/change-the-language-for-date-in-php)

Comment: It's only 12 items in an array that is needed to str_replace it. Personally I would not spend the time to fix that. I'd just make a translation table. Or even better, just use `$array_months[date("n")]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works for a CodeIgniter site hosted on an Ubuntu server.

1. Check if locale is installed and available on the server by running `locale -a` in the terminal. *(If your locale is in the list jump to point 3)*
2. Install desired locale by running `sudo apt-get install language-pack-XX`. *(Replace XX with your language. `se` for swedish. [List of all available packs](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=language-pack-&searchon=names))*
3. Add `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'sv_SE.utf8');` to `app/application/config/config.php` *(Switch to desired locale. [List of all locales](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3191729/1052393))*
4. Use `strftime('%B', ...)` instead of `date('F', ...)`

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in comments above it's very easy to translate manually.
First item in array has to be empty since arrays start with 0 and months start with 1.
Or you have to subtract one from date() but either way this looks in the array for the numeric month and echos the value (month).

```
$array_months = ["empty", "januari", "februari", "mars", "april", "maj", "juni", "juli", "augusti", "september", "oktober", "november", "december"];

$input = "2017-04-04";
Echo $array_months[date("n", strtotime($input))];
```

https://3v4l.org/MDLPO