# Carbon date language not change on format

Tags: php, laravel, format, php-carbon

I tried to change my Carbon language to "fr",
my appServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
{
    Carbon::setLocale('fr');
}
```

and in my model i have

```
protected $appends = [
        'humman_created_at'
    ];

    public function getHummanCreatedAtAttribute(){
        return $this->created_at->formatLocalized('%d %B %Y');
    }
```

when i dd humman_created_at i got `"25 November 2021"` but if i tried these

```
$this->created_at->monthName  => novembre
$this->created_at->diffForHumans() => il y a une semaine
```

I got french language return but my format date still `en`

Comment: The 'dd' function is a standard PHP function. Like every standard PHP function, Carbon will / can not translate the output of it. If you also want to translate the PHP output, you could / should try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910912/change-the-language-for-date-in-php

Comment: It looks like it's a bug. See https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/issues/2178 : `->localeDayOfWeek actually use the translations of your OS and the locale setting of LC_TIME while dayName use the internal translations of Carbon and the locale set via Carbon::setLocale() (so the one set by Laravel). Sorry for the confusion, that's legacy stuff (before Carbon handled translation on its own, it was delegated to setlocale and formatLocalized which use strftime but this approach is no longer recommended as the supported languages and their encoding differ from an OS to an other).`

Comment: According to the duplicate, you want `->translatedFormat('d F Y')` instead.